# Show percentages of classes by date on power BI

Tags: group-by, powerbi

I have the following table on Power BI:

[image]

From this I want to make a plot with the percenta of each class by date, E.G.

For 12-02-18 there are four records, 3 A and 1 C hence the percentage it would be A 75% and C 25%.

So far I have mede a groupby by Date and Class getting the below table:

[image]

From where I made the following plot:

Which has the actual values for each class:

[image]

But not the percentages.

Answer (score 0):

PowerBI allows you to do so quite easily, just change the formatting to "show value as percentage of grand total", as shown in the picture bellow.

[percentage of grand total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/347LE.png)

Comment: That doesnt work in this case, I want the values as percentages of the day not the total.

Comment: I see. In that case, i would try to create metric, which calculates the percentage.
It should be:

`measure = divide(sum(Recuento), distinctcount(class), 0)`

Which is just a fancy way to divide sum by count of classes, and if that should fail, return 0